# Form fails to submit after validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following code, validation works fine, but it doesnt submit

```
jQuery("#form_driver").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    //check if email exists
    jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checkmail.php",
                data: ({
                    email: jQuery("#email").val()
                }),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                   
                    if(data == 0) {
                        alert("Email doesnt exist");
                        return false;
                    }else if (data==1){
                        alert("The Email is already linked to your location!");
                        return false;
                    }else if (data==2){
                        jQuery("#form_driver").submit();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
});
```

Unbelievable what it outputs to the console,
Its driving me crazy, it iterates forever, I had to stop it manually

[image]

Comment: Did you try without this part: `jQuery("#form_driver").submit();` ? - its just re-starting the validation, or?

Comment: @Sergio I just did, one good thing that it stopped iterating the console output, just gave me a 2 once, but still didn't submit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit the form passed to the submitHandler. You are reselecting the form via jQuery instead. See [the api.](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Try this instead:

```
jQuery("#form_driver").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    //check if email exists
    jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checkmail.php",
                data: ({
                    email: jQuery("#email").val()
                }),
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {

                    if(data == 0) {
                        alert("Email doesnt exist");
                        return false;
                    }else if (data==1){
                        alert("The Email is already linked to your location!");
                        return false;
                    }else if (data==2){
                        form.submit();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
});
```